# padding images using php imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I need to create square images with no image loss. I found a tool that does the job as a bash script using ImageMagick but can never seem to be able to do it with php Imagick.

The script I found is called squareup from http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/squareup/index.php

My code looks like this currently:

```
$image = new Imagick($srcimage);
$image->setCompressionQuality(100);
if ($image->getImageHeight() <= $image->getImageWidth()) 
  $image->resizeImage($maxsize, 0, Imagick::FILTER_MITCHELL, 1);
else 
  $image->resizeImage(0, $maxsize, Imagick::FILTER_MITCHELL, 1);

$h=$image->getImageHeight();
$w=$image->getimagewidth();
$hlarge=0;
$wlarge=0;
if ($w>$h) {
  $diff=intval(($w-$h)/2);
  $wlarge=1;
  $h=$w;
} else {
  $diff=intval(($h-$w)/2);
  $w=$h;
  $hlarge=1;
}
$newimage = new Imagick();
if ($image->getImageColorspace() == Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK) {
  $fg="cmyk(0,0,0,0)";
  $fg_pixel=new ImagickPixel($fg);
  $newimage->newImage($w, $h, $fg_pixel);
  $newimage->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
} else {
  $newimage->newImage($w, $h, new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));
}
$newimage->compositeImage($image,\Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER,0,0);
$newimage->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$newimage->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$newimage->stripImage();
$newimage->writeImage($contactimage);
$newimage->destroy();
$image->destroy();
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Squareup is my script. But I do not know Imagick to help you convert it. Why not just call it from PHP exec()? The script and ImageMagick needs to run on RGB images and not CMYK.

Comment: If you want to simple crop or pad to square, see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#square

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do pad to square or crop to square in ImageMagick 6 is as follows:

Input:

[image]

```
size=`convert hatching_orig.jpg -format "%[fx:max(w,h)]" info:`
convert hatching_orig.jpg -background red -gravity center -extent ${size}x${size} hatching_pad.jpg
```

[image]

```
size=`convert hatching_orig.jpg -format "%[fx:min(w,h)]" info:`
convert hatching_orig.jpg -background red -gravity center -extent ${size}x${size} hatching_crop.jpg
```

[image]

Same command, but different size variable.

In IM 7, you can do each in one command line.

These commands should be easy to convert to Imagick, I would expect. But should be done in sRGB colorspace. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.extentimage.php